# AWS SageMaker Inference tutorial - ClientError: An error occurred when calling the CreateModel operation

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sagemaker

I got stuck when following AWS SageMaker model inference tutorial.
https://aws.amazon.com/getting-started/hands-on/machine-learning-tutorial-deploy-model-to-real-time-inference-endpoint/?nc1=h_ls

On Step 3, line 13, I'll get the error: ClientError: An error occurred (ValidationException) when calling the CreateModel operation: Could not access model data at s3://sagemaker-sample-files/models/xgb-fraud/fraud-det-xgb-model.tar.gz. Please ensure that the role "arn:aws:iam::xxx:role/service-role/AmazonSageMaker-ExecutionRole-xxx" exists and that its trust relationship policy allows the action "sts:AssumeRole" for the service principal "sagemaker.amazonaws.com". Also ensure that the role has "s3:GetObject" permissions and that the object is located in us-west-2.

I have checked all my permissions:

AmazonSageMaker-ExecutionPolicy:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:DeleteObject",
                "s3:ListBucket"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Trust relationship:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "Service": "sagemaker.amazonaws.com"
            },
            "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
        }
    ]
}
```

But still getting the error. Any ideas?

Comment: Can you try to give the S3 Full Access Policy and let us know if you have an issue?

Comment: how did you solve this?, I have the same issue

Comment: I had the same issue. My issue was that I set the region to `us-west-2` instead of `us-east-1` as what the tutorial suggests https://aws.amazon.com/tutorials/machine-learning-tutorial-deploy-model-to-real-time-inference-endpoint/.